# Destroy all session variables with PHP

Tags: php, session-variables

I am trying to get rid of a bunch of session variables in PHP. I mean completely get rid of them.

I have tried some different approaches. For example:

```
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
header('location: '.MAINPATH);
```

I have also tried using various compinations of session_unset, unset, setcookie etc. with the above commands.
I have of course tested if the session variables remains by doing:

```
echo $_SESSION['member_id'];
```

All of my session variables still remains for som reason.
Can anyone figure out what the problem might be?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

FWI: I am using PHP 5.5

UPDATE:
I tried changing my code to the following:

```
echo $_SESSION['member_id'];
session_unset();
session_destroy();
echo $_SESSION['member_id'];
```

which resulted in this output:

> 1000004 Notice: Undefined index: member_id in...

This should mean that the session variable is deletede right? The weird thing is, that when I am going back to my front page, the session variable is available again.

Comment: are you doing the `echo $_SESSION['member_id']` before or after a page refresh? the $_SESSION array will hold onto values from the current page load before it gets to your unset code, which will take effect on the next server request. Also make sure you started the session on the page before you get to the destroy function

Comment: echo $_SESSION['member_id'] after page refresh.. And yes I am using session_start() before the above codes

Comment: is the member_id the same value before and after the session_destroy() ??

Comment: Yes it is the same :p

Comment: YOU'VE BROKEN PHP!...on a more related note, try removing the `$_SESSION = array();` line and double check that the session isn't being re-instated by some sort of caching mechanism that you've set up.

Comment: Check out my update to the question..

Comment: Omg! Do I feel stupid now.. apparently i have forgotten about a test call that I made to my log in method in my code, which is called everytime my DB class is being instantiated.. Which means that it will attempt to log in with fixed values and setting my sessions values all over again, every time I refresh any page.. So sorry that if I wasted your time :P

Comment: aha no worries, I've definitely done the same thing, thats why i asked if it was being reinstated on each page refresh

Comment: Well, ou've helped me in the right direction though. So thanks . Have a good one :)

Answer (score 5):

One more time, can you do a quick try:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $helper = array_keys($_SESSION);
    foreach ($helper as $key){
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
?>
```

Comment: I created 3 files to test the destroying sessions and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code :-

```
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

use within php tag

Comment: You cant use `session_regenerate_id()` when there is no active session (it's obviously impossible to regenerate the id of a session which does not exist). The rest of this is sound advice, however.

Answer (score -3):

You can use session_unset() to clear all session variables.